# Supremum of a set equals to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, infinity

How to prove this statement?

> Suppose $E\subset \mathbb{R}$.
> If $\sup(E)=\infty$, then for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n< \sup(E)$. Moreover, we can construct a sequence $(x_n)\subset E$ such that $x_n>n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

From that statement, I know that $E$ is unbounded above, i.e. $\forall M\in \mathbb{R}, \exists x \in E$, such that $x>M$.

Then, since $E$ is unbounded above on $\mathbb{R}$, then $(x_n)$ is unbounded above, i.e. $\forall M\in \mathbb{R}, |x_n|>M, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried to prove that statement by using definition of supremum below:
$\sup(E)=s \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon>0, \exists x\in  E$ such that $s-\epsilon<x$.

And I think to use Archimedian property, but I am still get stuck to prove that.

Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: When $\sup$ is $+\infty$, then you cannot use statement with $\varepsilon$.

Comment: If you are allowing supremums to take on infinite values, then the *true* equivalence is: $\sup E = s$ if and only if $s$ is an upper bound of $E,$ and for every $t < s$ there is $u \in E$ such that $t < u.$ Unfortunately, trying to subtract $\varepsilon$ from $\infty$ will still be $\infty.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E has no finite upper bound $\implies$ is unbounded above, i.e., $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists x_n\in E$, such that $x_n>n$.
Let $S=\{x_n\}$ be set of these $x_n$ which is a subset of these E.
$\implies x_n<\text{Sup(E)}\implies n<\text{Sup(E) } \forall n$.